# jQuery return undefined when work with String.FromCharCode

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery code that must change Cyrillic input to Latin. This looking for position of Cyrillic char in array and replace it's with Latin Char, unfortunately I'm receiving undefined.

```
$("input[name*=Name]").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.charCode >= 1000 && e.charCode <= 1103) {
                var englishchars = ["a", "b", "v", "g", "d", "e", "yo", "zh", "z", "i", "yi", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "r", "s", "t", "u", "f", "kh", "c", "ch", "sh", "shch", "i", "e", "yu", "ya"];
                var slavicchars = ["a", "б", "в", "г", "д", "е", "ё", "ж", "з", "и", "й", "к", "л", "м", "н", "о", "п", "р", "c", "т", "у", "ф", "х", "ц", "ч", "ш", "щ", "ы", "э", "ю", "я"];
                var verified = String.fromCharCode(e.key).match(/[^а-яё]/);
                if (verified) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //If it's first char return, if not - get last char
                    var lastchar = this.value.length > 1 ? this.value.substr(-1) : this.value;
                    //Get position of Cyrillic char in array
                    var russiancharindex = jQuery.inArray(lastchar, slavicchars);
                    //Looking for corresponding Latin char
                    var englishcharindex = englishchars[russiancharindex];
                    this.value = this.value.replace(lastchar, englishcharindex);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where exactly you're getting `undefined`?

Comment: var lastchar = this.value.length > 1 ? this.value.substr(-1) : this.value; - this return empty string (not undefined actually).

Comment: With the `keypress` event `e.charCode` will be correct but `this.value` will be the value *before* the new keystroke is registered. Try changing `.keypress` to `.keyup`.

Comment: ... and change `e.charCode` to `e.which`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.fromCharCode(e.which)`. `e.key` is not a property.